# Python Code to Display fullscreen in main object (tkinter and PIL)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, python-imaging-library, fullscreen

With this code I can display an Image in full screen mode.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def showPIL(pilImage):
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    root.focus_set()
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.destroy()))
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.configure(background='black')
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
    if imgWidth > w or imgHeight > h:
        ratio = min(w / imgWidth, h / imgHeight)
        imgWidth = int(imgWidth * ratio)
        imgHeight = int(imgHeight * ratio)
        pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth, imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w / 2, h / 2, image=image)
    root.mainloop()


img1 = Image.open("img1.png")
img2 = Image.open('img2.png')

while True:
    n = int(input('Numero: '))
    if n == 1:
        showPIL(img1)
        continue
    elif n == 2:
        showPIL(img2)
        continue
    else:
        break
```

But I have a problem... 
The image that opens does not come as the main object on the screen, sometimes it is behind some open window or program ... How do I leave as the main screen?

Comment: Change the `e.widget.quit()` to `e.widget.destroy()` in your button so you only exit the mainloop.

Comment: thaaanks! @StevoMitric

Comment: How do I make this window open with the image being a priority on the screen? Sometimes it opens behind other programs @StevoMitric

Comment: You can put this `root.attributes("-topmost", True)` under that `root.bind`.

Comment: Good job! @StevoMitric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can put this root.attributes("-topmost", True) under that
>   root.bind. @StevoMitric

that solved my question.